# Rstudio: en Lectura mensaje de Advertencia con archivo .CSV

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy tratando de avanzar en un ejercicio para entregar a un seminario y gracias a ustedes he podido ir solucionando. Ahora estoy con otra incidencia:

En bibliostylo = read.csv()

en la consola sale el siguiente mensaje de advertencia:
In read.tabele(file=file, header=header, sep=sep, quote=quote, :incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on ()

Probé actualizar el archivo .csv en Zotero, y da el mismo error. Luego puse una lista bibliográfica que nos pasó el profesor, y con esa funciona. Pero, preciso probar con mi archivo.

Agradezco ayuda!

Saludos

Comment: El warning lo que te está diciendo es que al archivo le falta una última línea en blanco, es decir, a la última línea le falta el caracter de fin de linea. Edita el archivo, te paras el final de la última línea y presionas el "enter/return", lo guardas y vuélvelo a probar.